# Currency formatting in iOS

Tags: ios

I want to format multiple currencies correctly in an iOS app.

Currently, our backend exposes monetary values as a positive integer in the smallest currency unit (e.g., 100 cents to charge $1.00 or 100 to charge ¥100, a zero-decimal currency). This is consistent with the way we actually create charges when interacting w/ our payment processor.

My question is, given a currency code and this 'smallest possible unit', is it possible to appropriately format currency using Foundation's `NumberFormatter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the strange way you store the values, it seems you need to know whether a value need to be divided or not and by how much.

Based on the two examples you give, you can do this by looking at the formatter setup for currency and get the value of the `maximumFractionDigits`. Use that to calculate the power of 10 need to divide your number by. Then format the resulting number.

Example:

```
let amount = 100 // your raw value
let cf = NumberFormatter()
cf.currencyCode = "USD" // set based on your value
cf.numberStyle = .currency
let factor = pow(10.0, Double(cf.maximumFractionDigits))
let value = Double(amount) / factor
let string = cf.string(for: value)
```

This results in:

> $1.00

If the same code is run with a `currencyCode` of `JPY`, then the result is:

> ¥100

The exact output will depend on the user's locale of course.

Comment: thanks! out of curiosity, why do you consider this a strange way to store values?

Comment: Just used to seeing values stored as decimals.